# Execute SQL Scripts in a Spring Boot Commandline Application

Tags: spring-boot, command-line

I have a Spring Boot command line application packaged as a Jar which will take database details from the user. Using those details, I have to connect to the database and execute .sql file against that database
For example:

Seed the database programmatically
Execute scripts against the database

Can anyone help me with an option or link as to how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need a spring boot app for this? Can't you use the DB provided cmd or UI clients and execute the SQL scripts directly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide to getting your parameters into your Spring Boot app:

https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-passing-command-line-arguments-example/

Here's a guide to running logic on startup:

https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring